# I own a mutual fund that owns voting shares, who gets the vote?

Tags: stocks, mutual-funds, financial-literacy

I was looking at [FSCSX](https://fundresearch.fidelity.com/mutual-funds/summary/316390822) and noticed that it owns some Google Class A shares. These shares get 1 vote each (Yeah I know Google voting shares cant really influence anything, lets ignore that). Who actually gets the vote in this case? Would it be me, or the mutual fund owner?

Comment: The fund managers, I think, simply because the bookkeeping to try to assign ownership of specific fractional shares would be expensive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will not get a vote on any issues of the underlying stock.   The mutual fund owner/manager will do the voting.

> In 2004, the Securities and Exchange Commission (SEC) required that
>   fund companies disclose proxy votes, voting guidelines and conflicts
>   of interest in the voting process. All funds must make these
>   disclosures to the SEC through an N-PX filing, which must either be
>   available to shareholders on the fund company's websites or upon
>   request by telephone. You can also find your fund's N-PX filing on the
>   SEC website.  -- http://www.investopedia.com/articles/mutualfund/08/acting-in-interest.asp

Comment: The exception is company shares within the 401K program. I have always been given a proxy vote. That has not been the case for the underlying stocks for a mutual fund.

Comment: 401k is more akin to an IRA than a mutual fund - the shares you own are segregated from those that others own, and held in your name. In a mutual fund, the shares the fund owns are all in one account and not segregated.